# Python- Reading and Appending a File

Tags: python, file, append

I am trying to create a program that asks a user for input "name" and checks to make sure that the name is alphabetic, not too long, and not in a file called Unacceptable_Names (that contains inappropriate names)

To make sure that each user of the program doesn't use the same name, when a player enters a name I append it to Unacceptable_Names, then when the next player plays it should give them an error if they enter a name in this file.

The code below works for the words already created in the file, but when I replay and enter the same name I do not get an error. Can someone help troubleshoot why the name is not being checked?

```
def Char_Name(self,name):
    string1=str(name).lower()
    unacceptable_names=open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt", "r")
    unacceptable_names2=open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt", "a")
    names_list= []
    for line in unacceptable_names.readlines():
        for i in line.split(","):
            names_list.append(i.strip())
    if name.isalpha()==False:
        print("You entered a name containing non-alphabetic characters, pease reenter a new name:")
        main()
    elif len(name)>=10:
        print("You entered a name containing 10 or more characters, pease reenter a new name:")
        main()
    elif string1 in names_list:
        print("You entered a name containing bad words or a name already in use! Try again.")
        main()
    else:
        unacceptable_names2.write("\n"+str(name)+",")
        unacceptable_names2.close()
        self.character_name=name
```

This is what unacceptable_names looks like after entering a name "Emily": [along with some other bad words in the file before it- all of which if entered give me an error]

wrinkled starfish,
xx,
xxx,
yaoi,
yellow showers,
yiffy,
zoophilia,
Emily,

However, if I manually go into the text file and write "Emily" exactly how it is above, it will give me the error message that I need.

Comment: *"I do get an error"* Which error? If possible please show the exact error message and if appropriate, the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Did you check if the file remains after you stop playing first time ?

Comment: No I said I do not get an error- that is the problem. The name is appending into the file, but when I restart the program (with the name in the file) I do not get an error when trying to enter the name. For example, I will enter the name "Emily" the first time. Emily appends to the file. If I restart the program and enter "Emily" again, I do not get an error that Emily is already in the file.

Comment: Does the `Char_Name` functions being called after restart?

Comment: Try `unacceptable_names2.write(name + '\n')`

Comment: By the way, you are append name without adding `','` character and later trying to split name by `','` delimiter

Answer (score 1):

This line `unacceptable_names2.write(name)` appends names to the same line. 
You should each name with a `,` after each name. Only then will

```
for line in unacceptable_names.readlines():
        for i in line.split(","):
            names_list.append(i.strip())`
```

work.

Current file content after `unacceptable_names2.write(name)`:

```
helloonetwothree
```

What you want it to be:

```
hello,one,two,three
```

Updated code:

```
def Char_Name(self,name):
    string1=str(name).lower()
    unacceptable_names=open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt", "r")
    unacceptable_names2=open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt", "a")
    names_list= []
    for line in unacceptable_names.readlines():
        for i in line.split(","):
            names_list.append(i.strip())
    if name.isalpha()==False:
        print("You entered a name containing non-alphabetic characters, pease reenter a new name:")
        main()
    elif len(name)>=10:
        print("You entered a name containing 10 or more characters, pease reenter a new name:")
        main()
    elif string1 in names_list:
        print("You entered a name containing bad words or a name already in use! Try again.")
        main()
    else:
        unacceptable_names2.write(name+',')
        unacceptable_names2.close()
        self.character_name=name
```

Update:

Add `i.strip()` to the code above. 
You are somehow adding a whitespace to the beginning of each name.
So when you search for `yiffy` it is not able to find the match. Because it is stored as `yiffy` instead.

```
In [54]: 'wrinkled starfish, xx, xxx, yaoi, yellow showers, yiffy, zoophilia, Emily,'.split(','
   ....: )
Out[54]: 
['wrinkled starfish',
 ' xx',
 ' xxx',
 ' yaoi',
 ' yellow showers',
 ' yiffy',
 ' zoophilia',
 ' Emily',
 '']
```

Comment: `','` should be before `name` to separate it from previous one

Comment: Not necessarily. `Split` just looks for the character anywhere in the string.

Comment: May be I'm not right, but output would be like: `hello,one,twothree,` and after `split` you will get `['hello', 'one', 'twothree', '']`

Comment: I see how you mean- but changing unacceptable_names2.write(name) to unacceptable_names2.write(name +",") Is still not fixing the problem

Comment: @Megan what about my solution?

Comment: @Megan: your problem was an already used name was not being rejected when entered again. I find my answer to be working fine; updated it with output.

Comment: No it is not working either. I am beginning to think the error might be in a different part of the code- I am appending what my file looks like to the original question. I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working either" ? Can you try a few names and paste the content of 'Unacceptable_Names.txt' into the question as well ?

Comment: Yes: see updated question.   I will enter the name Emily. It will update to my file as shown in the question- but if I run the program again and enter Emily it will not work. However, if I manually enter Emily in the exact same formatting in the text file, it will work. I am honestly dumbfounded.

Comment: Updated my answer. Use `i.strip()` in the `names_list.append(i.strip())`, because the names you are saving into the file have a whitespace in the beginning of each name (based on the ouput-file content you have pasted in the file).

Comment: I tried that as well but same problem- the code works fine if I try to enter yiffy... it is very specifically when I try to enter one of the names that I have appended that the code doesnt work.

Comment: Can you try using this line `str(name)+','` than `"\n"+str(name)+","` ? You are splitting by just a comma, why add a `'\n'` ?

Comment: It didnt show when I put it in the question, but I added "\n" because in the text file, each name is on a different line, I will try it again without the "\n" for good measure though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77393/discussion-between-fixxxer-and-megan).

Answer (score 0):

```
def Char_Name(self,name):
    string1=str(name).lower()
    unacceptable_names=open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt", "r")
    unacceptable_names2=open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt", "a")
    names_list= []
    for line in unacceptable_names.readlines():
        for i in line.split(","):
            names_list.append(i)
    if name.isalpha()==False:
        print("You entered a name containing non-alphabetic characters, pease reenter a new name:")
        main()
    elif len(name)>=10:
        print("You entered a name containing 10 or more characters, pease reenter a new name:")
        main()
    elif string1 in names_list:
        print("You entered a name containing bad words or a name already in use! Try again.")
        main()
    else:
        unacceptable_names2.write(',' + str(name) ) # <------- 
        unacceptable_names2.close()
        self.character_name=name
```

or you can change last `else` into:

```
else:
        unacceptable_names2.write('\n' + str(name) + '\n')
        unacceptable_names2.close()
        self.character_name=name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure to exact match names. If you simply match in python, it can confuse one name to be other. Example,there are two users with similar user names example:
1) Megan
2) Megan2015.
In a simple match case: if you search for Megan, python may find Megan2015 and say it has found it, since "Megan" in "Megan2015"

```
def exact_match(phrase, word):
import re

b = r'(\s|^|$)'
res = re.match(b + word + b, phrase, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
return bool(res)  # returns true or false

def Char_Name(self,name):

string1=str(name).lower()
unacceptable_names=open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt", "r")
unacceptable_names2=open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt","a")
names_list= []

for line in unacceptable_names.readlines():

    for i in line.split(","):
        names_list.append(i)

if name.isalpha()==False:
    print("You entered a name containing non-alphabetic characters, please  reenter a new name:")
    main()

elif len(name)>=10:
    print("You entered a name containing 10 or more characters, pease reenter a new name:")
    main()

elif:
    for n in range(0,len(names_list)):

        if exact_match(string1, names_list[n]) == True:
            print("You entered a name containing bad words or a name already in use! Try again.")
            main()
else:
    unacceptable_names2.write(str(name + " , ") )
    unacceptable_names2.close()
    self.character_name=name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write each name on separate lines and you won't need to aplit at all, make a set of the names when you open the file and use a+ to open once for reading and appending:

```
def Char_Name(self,name):
    string1 = name.lower()
    with open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt", "a+") as f:
        unacceptable_names = set(line.rstrip() for line in f)
    if not name.isalpha():
        print("You entered a name containing non-alphabetic characters, please re-enter a new name:")
        main()
    elif len(name) >= 10:
        print("You entered a name containing 10 or more characters, please re-enter a new name:")
        main()
    elif string1 in unacceptable_names:
        print("You entered a name containing bad words or a name already in use! Try again.")
        main()
    f.write("{}\n".format(name))
    self.character_name = name
```

It might be a better idea to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to store a set of names.

I  would also use a while loop asking the user for their name in the  loop instead of repeatedly calling main.

```
def Char_Name(self):
    with open("C://Users//Documents//Unacceptable_Names.txt", "a+") as f:
        unacceptable_names = set(line.rstrip() for line in f)
    while True:
        name = input("Please enter your username")
        _name = name.lower()
        if _name in unacceptable_names:
            print("You entered a name containing bad words or a name already in use! Try again.")
        elif _name.isalpha():
            print("You entered a name containing non-alphabetic characters, please re-enter a new name:")
        elif len(name) >= 10:
            print("You entered a name containing 10 or more characters, please re-enter a new name:")
        else:
            break
    f.write("{}\n".format(name))
    self.character_name = name
```

There is no need to ever use readlines unless you actually want a list, if you are going to build a container of names then a set is the most efficient way to check for membership.